# ORDER BY based on maximum number of row appearence

Tags: mysql, sql

Table Fields:
shop_id , product_id

1. I want a list of all shops having specific products(should have at least 1 product)
2. results should be sorted on basis of shops having maximum number of specified products

I could write sql query for 1st part, but the list is not sorted according to the shops that match maximum number of products

```
SELECT 
    shop_id,
    product_id
FROM
    products_table
WHERE
    product_id IN (1,2,3)
ORDER BY ???
```

Is there a optimal solution?

Comment: *maximum number of products* you mean **items in stock** ? or you mean that all 3 items (id=1,2,3) presented in that shop?

Comment: If shop has all 3 items, after sorting it should be ranked first, if it has 2 items it should be ranked 2nd and so on

Comment: what is you tables structure then? do you have just 1 table `products_table`? or 2 `products_table_`+`shops_table` or 3 `products_table`, `shops_table`, `stock_table`?

Comment: single table products table, 
(1,1), (1,2), (2,2), means shop 1 has products 1 and 2, shop 2 has product 2

Answer (score 3):

Join with a subquery that gets the counts for each shop, and order by that.

```
SELECT a.shop_id, a.product_id
FROM products_table AS a
JOIN (SELECT shop_id, COUNT(*) AS product_count
      FROM products_table
      WHERE product_id in (1, 2, 3)
      GROUP BY shop_id) AS b
ON a.shop_id = b.shop_id
WHERE product_id IN (1, 2, 3)
ORDER BY b.product_count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

A query like this will avoid repeating the list of product_ids:

```
with sp as (
    select shop_id, product_id
    from products_table
    where product_id IN (1,2,3)
)
select
    shop_id, product_id,
    (select count(*) from sp as sp2 where sp2.shop_id = sp.shop_id) as shop_count
from sp
order by shop_count desc
```

But now I see you're using MySQL so it won't work out for you although it can be expanded:

```
select
    shop_id, product_id,
    (
        select count(*) from products_table as p2
        where product_id in (1,2,3) and p2.shop_id = p.shop_id
    ) as shop_count
from products_table as p
where product_id in (1,2,3)
order by shop_count desc;
```

It's essentially the same query but the join is implied. I'm under the impression that MySQL doesn't always handle correlated queries very efficiently. I think the flavor of Barbar's answer is the one you'll have to use unless you create a temporary table mirroring "sp" above.

As a side note, I study languages and it's interesting to me that I chose to call my computed column "shop_count" while the other Barmar went with "product_count. I focused on shop as the center of my attention though we're actually counting up products. To me "shop_count" indicated "count per shop" while Barbar might describe his as "count of products". By no means am I arguing that one approach is more valid or natural. It's just fascinating to me to see the different perspective that people can take.

Comment: . . I find Barmar's terminology easier to follow.  Each row in the result set is a "shop".  The column is the count of products.

Comment: I think that from a programmer's standpoint I would have to agree and indeed I would probably have wanted to argue with somebody doing exactly what I just did. I guess that's why it intrigues me.